# Distribute ipa for Q&A (ad-hoc vs development-export)

Tags: ios, deployment, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

Apple has this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) which describes how to export your app for ad-hoc installation via iTunes.

One thing I am struggeling with is the differentiation between exporting for Ad-Hoc Deployment and exporting for Development Deployment.

I have the following circumstances:

- The ipa should be installed via iTunes
- All target-devices UUIDs are registred in the devcenter
- The apple-id's installing those ipa's are NOT registred

Which option do I have to use and does that also always require me to generate an Ad Hoc-Profile as new iOS certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Added udid's iOS certificate to install to the test device, IPA can not be sent directly to the phone installation.